# pop up a swipe view when a button click in android

Tags: android, popup, android-popupwindow

I have a swipe view with tabs.It runs well.But i want to pop up this menu when a button click.i have lots of images.i use Drawer layout but it run out of memory so i use the swipe menu.but i want to close and open this menu.is there any library?Any suggest or helpful links?

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

this is the example of android.
My swipe view have xml files and two java file.